# Want to associate a git commitId to a particular jenkins build using api or script inside jenkins postBuildAction

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We are performing some git commits from jenkins script(Execute shell). So the job is showing a different commitid, thats due to,  when the job starts, the last commit id different and when we complete the job the last commit id is different, as inside the job itself we are performing certain commits. Post which we are building the maven using same jenkins job as a final step. so we want to update the associated commitid with latest one. How we can do that? can someone please help?
[image]

Comment: Not in Jenkins itself, but we support this via external tool to show you all associated commits in Reliza Hub - https://plugins.jenkins.io/reliza-integration/

Comment: you mean we cannot do it with just jenkins alone we need a plugin to that?

Comment: Not just a plugin but you need an external tool. I am not aware of any plugin that will let you leverage just Jenkins for this task.